keyboard shortcut assignment not working key sync in SVN
I have seen this bug in "modern" eclipses because in those from years ago the default keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Alt + S) worked perfectly.
However, in the latest versions it doesn't work, nor does assigning me a new keyboard shortcut. It's strange to see that when I press "right mouse button --> Team --> Synchronize with Repository" I can see the shortcut in the context menu but the shortcut doesn't work. I have to use the mouse context menu.

I have also tried to see the shortcut with "Show key binding when command is invoked" and I can see on the screen that it shows the shortcut but it doesn't do anything.


I use subclipse:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse

In preferences Keys, set the cursor into the Bindings field and type Ctrl+Alt+S. If nothing will displayed, then something else (operating system or another tool) catches the shortcut. Otherwise filter for Ctrl+Alt+S to see whether other commands are bound to this key. By the way, the dark theme plugin you have installed patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). If you don't like the built-in themes, there are other ones that are more ergonomic,don't do this.
